# angularjs chaining promises not working , and angular.copy is not either

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

So my understanding is that i can loop over my FIRST returned set of objects

**Object =   vm.liberty**

Loop

```
vm.liberty.forEach(function (obj) {
```

My understanding of this  `obj` is that it is a reference and thus the `vm.liberty` object will get updated.... right?

I know that `console.log` is not reliable as it spits out results as soon as line it hit

However

```
     console.log('obj', obj);
```

That contains the DATA that i want,  I have added in a extended nested object to each record in the object ....

But someone either i'm not doing promise chaining correctly or something else

I even try to do a `angular.copy`

```
vm.liberty2 = angular.copy(vm.liberty);
```

That does not work , as `console.log(vm.liberty);` seems to be empty

Here is my function:

```
    var loadLiberty = function () {

        var promise1 = libertyService.getLibertyQuestions();
        promise1.then(function (response) {
            vm.liberty = response;
        }).then(function (res) {
            vm.liberty.forEach(function (obj) {
                promise2 = libertyService.getDirectives(obj.QuestionId)
                    .then(function (result) {
                        obj.directives = result;
                        console.log('obj', obj);
                        //vm.liberty.directives = result;


                    }, function (err) {
                        console.log('err', err);
                    });

            });

        });
        //vm.liberty2 = angular.copy(vm.liberty);
        console.log(vm.liberty);
        vm.liberty2 = angular.copy(vm.liberty);
        //return promise1;
    };
```

**Thoughts or suggestions ?**

Comment: You can only access the response inside the `then` handler, it won't be available before that will run.

Comment: what is a better way of writing this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `console.log(vm.liberty);` happens before your promises are resolved, that is why it still has its initial value.

Have a look at the following example:

```js
function loadLiberty() {

    const libertyQuestionsPromise = libertyService.getLibertyQuestions();

    libertyQuestionsPromise
        .then(x => vm.liberty = x)
        .then(() => {
            // hold promises which are getting directives in this array
            const promises = [];
            vm.liberty.forEach(obj => {
                // get directives for every obj
                const promise = libertyService
                    .getDirectives(obj.QuestionId)
                    .then(x => obj.directives = x);
                promises.push(promise);
            });
            // wait until all promises in the promises array are resolved
            return $q.all(promises);
        })
        .then(() => {
            // at this point the vm.liberty should be populated with results
            console.log(vm.liberty);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // handle any error which might have occurred in any of the promises in this chain
        });

}
```

Do not forget to inject the `$q` dependency in your service/controller.